# How to get dynamic column data linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have following code,

```
public List<MemberDto> GetMembers(out int rowCount,int pageIndex,int pageSize,  string seachColumn = "", string searchTerm = "", string sortBy = "", string sortDiection = "")
{
    var members = (from m in context.Members
                   where (string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTerm) || m.MemberNumber.Equals(searchTerm))
                         || (string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTerm) || m.LastName.Equals(searchTerm))
                   select m).AsEnumerable();
                   
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortBy))
    {
        PropertyDescriptor prop = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(EFModel.ClientData.Member)).Find(sortBy, true);
        members = (sortDiection.ToLower() == "descnding") ? members.OrderByDescending(x => prop.GetValue(x)).ToList() : members.OrderBy(x => prop.GetValue(x)).ToList();
    }

    rowCount =  (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTerm)) ? members.Count() : rowCount = context.Members.Count() ;
    
    members = members.Skip(pageIndex).Take(pageSize).ToList();

    List<MemberDto> memberDtos = new List<MemberDto>();
    mapper.Map(members, memberDtos);
    return memberDtos;
}
```

In the above code, I `seachColumn` value can be ("`a`","`b`",or ""). When `seachColumn` = "`a`" I need to search table data by column `MemberNumber` based on `searchTerm` value

When `seachColumn` = "`b`" I need to search table data by column `LastName`. based on `searchTerm` value

to achieve that I wrote following code.

```
if(seachBy == "a")
{
    var sa = (from m in context.Members
              where (string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTerm) || m.MemberNumber.Equals(searchTerm))
              select m).AsEnumerable();
}
else if (seachBy == "b")
{
    var sa = (from m in context.Members
              where (string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTerm) || m.LastName.Equals(searchTerm))
              select m).AsEnumerable();
}
```

I know, I tried code is bit fool. Have any proper way to do this?

Comment: If you're asking for a general code review, it's essentially off-topic in SO (as it can be quite subjective and promote discussions of differing opinions);  You'll need to add more focus on what you're asking and be specific, and it should promote fact-based answers. see [don't-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) as it relates to improving subjective questions.  Also, A general Code Review is on-topic for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is a better way to do this. First of all you want to do this all as an `IQueryable` - Why? - Because as soon as you do `.AsEnumerable()` or `.ToList()` the query is executed on the DB Server and the data is loaded into Memory.

So in your code here - because you have called `.AsEnumerable()` it has loaded all `context.Members.Where condition is true` into Memory:

```
var members = (from m in context.Members
                   where (string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTerm) || m.MemberNumber.Equals(searchTerm))
                         || (string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTerm) || m.LastName.Equals(searchTerm))
                   select m)
.AsEnumerable();
```

Your second part of code is pagination. What we normally do is write a `IQueryable` extension methods.

So add the following class with the 2 extension methods to a common location.

```
public static class IQueryableExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<T> ApplyPagination<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string sortDirection, string sortBy, int pageNumber, int pageSize)
    {
        var sortDirectionInternal = sortDirection == "asc" ? "OrderBy" : "OrderByDescending";

        var orderBy = sortBy;

        if (pageSize != -1)  // -1 is for All - I don't apply pagination if pageSize == -1.
        {
            return source.OrderBy(orderBy, sortDirectionInternal)
                    .Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize)
                    .Take(pageSize);
        }

        return source.OrderBy(orderBy, sortDirection);
    }

    public static IQueryable<T> OrderBy<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string ordering, string sortDirection)
    {
        var type = typeof(T);

        // Get Property to Sort By
        var property = type.GetProperty(ordering);

        // If Property is NULL (not found) - Just use the first Property (Default) to ORDER BY - as this will prevent Exception
        if (property == null)
        {
            property = type.GetProperties().First();
        }

        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(type, "p");
        var propertyAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, property);
        var orderByExp = Expression.Lambda(propertyAccess, parameter);
        var resultExp = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), sortDirection, new[] { type, property.PropertyType }, source.Expression, Expression.Quote(orderByExp));
        return source.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(resultExp);
    }
}
```

So now your above code will look something like this - I didn't use VS so there might be some sytnax errors:

```
// NOTE: you will need to include the namespace for the new IQueryableExtensions class

var members = (from m in context.Members
               where (string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTerm) || m.MemberNumber.Equals(searchTerm))
                     || (string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTerm) || m.LastName.Equals(searchTerm))
               select m);

// retrieve count only if you need to of total members that match the above criteria
rowCount = members.Count();

// This is all you need to do! - ApplyPagination(params) - 
members = members.ApplyPagination(sortDiection, sortBy, pageIndex, pageSize);

return mapper.Map<List<MemberDto>>(members);
```

Comment: What is your `pageNumber `? If it calculates to less than 0 you might get this error. My page number starts from 1, so for page1 it calculates as `.Skip(0)` and for page2 it caculates as `.Skip(1 * pageSize)`

Comment: Yup, that was the reason. but that order by not working properly. once  I not passing the `sortBy` . from this code part `property = type.GetProperties().First();` property  taking as `MemberId` according to the my table structure, but retrieving data is not showing as properly, It returns 25 records, but I can't understand what was that order.

Comment: Yup, that was the reason. but that order by not working properly. once  I not passing the `sortBy` . from this code part `property = type.GetProperties().First();` property  taking as `MemberId` according to the my table structure, but retrieving data is not showing as properly, It returns 25 records, but I can't understand what was that order.

Comment: Sorry sir, I think this happen because in my database firstname and lastname are always encrypted. That why  I think order part not working properly. how to handle this

Comment: obviously from the code if you don't pass `sortBy` it would take the first property from the type and `OrderBy` the first column/property. That is what the code `property = type.GetProperties().First();` does. read the comment in code `// If Property is NULL (not found) - Just use the first Property (Default) to ORDER BY - as this will prevent Exception`

Comment: for the ecryption part, seems like you will need to use `List ` or `Enumerable` instead of `IQueryable`. You didn't mention columns are encrypted in the question. 
But you can modfiy the above `class / methods ` to `List/Enumerable`

Comment: Sorry I forget to mention it sir, May I know what should I update correctly? can u please update the question. I'm really sorry

Comment: No sorry, it's pretty straight forward just changing the IQueryable to IEnumerable and then you query as it was before.

Comment: Thanks sir, really help ur answer

Comment: I only changed the both extension methods return type to `IEnumerable` . and changed this as `var members2 = members.ApplyPagination(sortDiection, sortBy, pageIndex, pageSize);  var members2Lst = members2 .ToList();`  But its makes me runtime error. what did I do wrong here sir

Comment: `members2Lst` set for the mapper